# Complexity of Equivalence of Categories

Tags: complexity-theory, category-theory

I'm trying to find a characterization of the computational complexity of the equivalence problem for finitely presented categories.

Given two categories C and D, an equivalence is two functors F : C -> D and G : D -> C and two natural isomorphisms FG -> I_D and I_C -> GF, where I_C : C -> C and I_D : D -> D are the identity functors on C and D.

The equivalence problem is to determine the existence of an equivalence for two finitely presented categories.  This problem is undecidable, but I am hoping that it is still recursively enumerable or co-recursively enumerable.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_categories

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_presentation

Comment: I'm sorry this has had no response yet. Have you tried asking it over at http://math.stackexchange.com/ or http://mathoverflow.net/?